# dropdownlist in html table

Tags: html, asp.net, drop-down-menu, html-table

I am using asp.net and I would like to create a table which allows the user to enter multiple rows. some of the rows are to be dropdownlists. I dont know how to do this.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: what do you want exactly? the user will add multiple rows to the table? or will select items from a dropdownlist?

Comment: i want to user to add rows to the table so that s/he can enter fields, of which one will be a dropdownlist

Answer (score 0):

What are you using for data storage?  Are you using SQL Server?  Are your drop-down lists powered by enumberations or reference data?  What version of .NET are you using?

It seems like you want to create a data entry application utilizing ASP.NET.  If your database is SQL server and you're uzing .NET version 3.5, I recommend using a simple GridView with a LinqDataSource.  Check out [Scott Guthrie's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx) for some cool examples.